# Makefile to base64 encode kubernetes secrets

Tags: bash, sed, makefile, kubernetes

In Kubernetes, secret resources are base64 encoded. This is an example yaml file from the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  USERNAME: bXktYXBwCg==
  PASSWORD: YV44KXlcNzw4QUF4YWEoeV54
```

Where the two pieces of secret data: a username and a password were base64 encoded using:

```
echo -n 'my-app' | base64
echo -n 'a^8)y\7<8AAxaa(y^x' | base64
```

The workflow I would like is to have a version of the yaml file with my *naked* secrets and a `Makefile` which could produce the base64 encoded version.

This is where I got to before I got stuck:

The input (`my-secrets-naked.yaml`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  USERNAME: my-app
  PASSWORD: a^8)y\7<8AAxaa(y^x
```

The `Makefile`:

```
base64:
    @echo "Computing base64 of secret values..."
    cat my-secrets-naked.yaml | bash base64_secrets.sh > my-secrets-base64.yaml
```

The `base64_secrets.sh` script:

```
sed -r 's/(\s+[A-Z]\S+:\s*)(.*)/echo "\1$(echo -n "\2" | base64 -w0 )"/e;s/  -//'
```

The command: `make base64`

The output (`my-secrets-base64.yaml`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  USERNAME: bXktYXBw
  PASSWORD: YV44KXkHPDhBQXhhYSh5Xng=
```

Ideally, I would like the `sed` inside the `Makefile` rather than a separate script but I couldn't figure it out. But most importantly the base64 for the PASSWORD is wrong! It breaks for secrets with backslashes in, in this case the `\7` causes problems. I can't figure out how to echo the unescaped characters whilst still using the `\2` back reference from the preceding `sed`. (`echo -E` doesn't work, it takes `\2` literally. No luck with `printf '%s' \2` either).

I know it seems like a specific question - but a good solution for this could be useful for all Kubernetes users?

If I get this workflow working I intend to extend it so the Makefile produces a 3rd file with the secrets redacted and hashed so safe to be committed in git, whilst still knowing when something changed.

---

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04, sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this with perl.

```
cat Makefile
base64:
        @echo "Computing base64 of secret values..."
        cat my-secrets-naked.yaml|perl -MMIME::Base64 -npe 's/^(\s+[A-Z]+:\s+)(.*)./"$$1".encode_base64($$2)/es;' > my-secrets-base64.yaml
```

Here is the output:

```
cat my-secrets-base64.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
data:
  USERNAME: bXktYXBw
  PASSWORD: YV44KXlcNzw4QUF4YWEoeV54
```

Comment: That's really clever, using the upper-case-edness of the fields to determine which to base64 encode.

Comment: It may have issues if the metadata `name:` field gets "FOO:bar", though, so maybe better to hard-code USERNAME|PASSWORD into the regex.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b I agree with you. best option to use the helm for kubernetes  app development

Comment: Thank you very much! I had to remove the last `.` in the search but I'm guessing that is because I have single byte Linux line endings and you had 2 byte Windows line endings.

Answer (score 9):

Consider using the `stringData` field instead of the `data` field and you can pass in unencoded value. It will still be stored as `data` internally and shows as such when queried back.

```
DESCRIPTION:
Secret holds secret data of a certain type. The total bytes of the values in the Data field must be less than MaxSecretSize bytes.

FIELDS:
   type <string>
     Used to facilitate programmatic handling of secret data.

   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/devel/api-conventions.md#resources

   data <object>
     Data contains the secret data. Each key must be a valid DNS_SUBDOMAIN or
     leading dot followed by valid DNS_SUBDOMAIN. The serialized form of the
     secret data is a base64 encoded string, representing the arbitrary (possibly
     non-string) data value here. Described in
     https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648#section-4

   kind <string>
     Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object
     represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits
     requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info:
     http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/devel/api-conventions.md#types-kinds

   metadata <Object>
     Standard object's metadata. More info:
     http://releases.k8s.io/HEAD/docs/devel/api-conventions.md#metadata

   stringData   <object>
     stringData allows specifying non-binary secret data in string form. It is
     provided as a write-only convenience method. All keys and values are merged
     into the data field on write, overwriting any existing values. It is never
     output when reading from the API.
```

I would perhaps suggest using JSON rather than YAML though.

Comment: I didn't know about `stringData`. Thank you.

Comment: That description for Secret comes from here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.16/#secret-v1-core 
Great way to learn about k8s objects!

Comment: Is easier than that. Run `oc explain secret` or `kubectl explain secret`.

Answer (score 2):

Although all props go to Graham for answering, let me make this answer more plastic. At least I missed it skipping through results.

Make use of `stringData` not having to base64encode your inputs in the first place.
Encoding will be taken care of when deploying the secret:

Non-encoded secrets in secrets definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: test-secret
stringData:
  USERNAME: my-app
  PASSWORD: a^8)y\7<8AAxaa(y^x
```

should end up as base64encoded in your cluster. Query with:

```
kubectl describe secret/test-secret

kubectl get secret test-secret -o jsonpath='{.data}'
```